# Add mapping resource from other JAR

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a jar file which has some mapping files I want to add then as mapping resource in hibernate.cfg.xml for that I added JAR in org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration..

```
    Configuration cfg=new Configuration();
    cfg.addJar(new File("C:\\Users\\amoghs\\.m2\\repository\\mkcl\\os\\personServiceBL\\1.0.1\\personServiceBL-1.0.1.jar"));
    cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    SchemaExport se=new SchemaExport(cfg);
    se.setDelimiter("\n#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    se.setOutputFile("E:\\ADFCreateScript.sql");
    se.create(true,true);
```

and in hibernate.cfg.xml I added..

```
<mapping resource="org/mkcl/personservices/models/Person.hbm.xml" />
```

Person.hbm.xml this xml file is in jar file.

when i execute java application I got this exception...

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processHbmXml(Configuration.java:3415)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processHbmXmlQueue(Configuration.java:3404)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3392)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1341)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.generateDropSchemaScript(Configuration.java:931)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.<init>(SchemaExport.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.<init>(SchemaExport.java:156)
    at mkcl.accreditation.model.GenrateSchema.main(GenrateSchema.java:34)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: field [countryCode] not found on java.util.List
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor.getField(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor.getField(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:174)
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor.getGetter(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:197)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.getter(ReflectHelper.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.reflectedPropertyClass(ReflectHelper.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.setTypeUsingReflection(SimpleValue.java:326)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.createProperty(HbmBinder.java:2286)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindComponent(HbmBinder.java:1994)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.createClassProperties(HbmBinder.java:2191)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.createClassProperties(HbmBinder.java:2141)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues(HbmBinder.java:407)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRootClass(HbmBinder.java:322)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRoot(HbmBinder.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processHbmXml(Configuration.java:3412)
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the entire jar to the Hibernate `Configuration`, then all the mappings (*.hbm.xml) it contains are automatically added to the `Configuration`. No need to add the following line in your hibernate.cfg.xml file :

```
<mapping resource="org/mkcl/personservices/models/Person.hbm.xml"/>
```